# Using IoC in an application that use a library that doesn't use IoC

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject, console-application, service-locator

I am currently using a library (SuperWebSocket) which is a websocket server library that use a bootstrap which know which instances to load from a configuration file. I have implemented a bootstrap class for this (however the instances arent loaded using IoC). Also the commands from this server are loaded from assemblies reflection. I wanted to use this server in conjonction with my DAL and service layer which use IoC. **My main problem is that i can't find a way to put this Console Application (Server) and cooperation with the lib in an IoC scenario without having to end up using the ServiceLocator.**

Normally the kernel (Ninject) should be located at the composition root (Look like to be the best practice from many around..) which is rather not possible to do in this case or at least i didn't found how so that why i am here. Also the commands are loaded from assemblies reflection. I could implement a CommandLoader however this is still a problem cause they all inherit from the same interface (Multibinding maybe?). I could make custom interface for each of them but i still can't find a way to load them automatically. Even if i found a way to load them, i still have to be able to get service from attributes which is not easy to do.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why not just wrap the external library in your own adapter that utilises your IoC container? It is a good practice to keep third-party libraries in one place with an abstraction over them anyway, in case you need to switch them out for something else or handle specific cases differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then the library is the entry point for all work done. In this situation it depends on the framework what to do. Here are some things you can do the first things are the preferred ones:

1. Inspect the library and find some way to hook into the framework to intercept the creation of your objects.
2. Call `kernel.Inject(this)` after an object is created by the library. Have a look at the `Ninject.Web` extension. There we added some base classes e.g. `NinjectWebPage` for `WebPage`. This new base class calls kernel.Inject after creation. New web pages can now be derived from that base class and use property injection to get dependencies.
3. Use the `ServiceLocator` pattern in the objects created by the libray. But just at this level. Anything deeper should use dependency injection.

Comment: Solution 3 seem fine with me. All the logic are located in commands which can be intercepted with Ninject. For specifics minimal stuff i can use the servicelocator but at least my commands can be reusable and can be interchanged which make the use of ioc here very useful. A big plus is that this will make my commands testable which is the main goal here. Thanks Remo for taking the time to answer this.